i am using heroku for deplying Springboot application and it showing error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
mp/cache/.m2/repository/com/example/17-SpringBoot-restapi-withDatabase/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/17-SpringBoot-restapi-withDatabase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  11.265 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-07T12:36:06Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 167.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://ashu-erail-app-dff688f5fc04.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/ashu-erail-app.git

[new branch]      main -> main


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
